# How to get the id of another table in sqlite3 Python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have a text file which contains tasks, firstnames, lastnames and scores. I am then creating two tables like this in python:

```
c.execute('create table if not exists persons (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name1 TEXT, name2 TEXT, UNIQUE(name1, name2))')


c.execute('create table if not exists scores (idPerson INTEGER, task INTEGER, score INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (idPerson) REFERENCES persons(id) ON DELETE CASCADE, UNIQUE(idPerson, task))')
```

I am trying to get the id from persons and inserting that into scores, but don't know if this is the right way to do it:

```
for lines in file:
    fields = lines.split(" ")
    name1 = fields[2]
    name2 = fields[3]
    point = fields[4]
    task = fields[1]
    persons = (name1, name2)
    c.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO persons (name1, name2) VALUES (?, ?)', persons)
    id = c.lastrowid
    scores = (id, task, point)
    c.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO scores (idPerson, task, score) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', scores)
```

But with this I am getting an foreign key error and I don't know what to do here?

Comment: Think about what happens when you try to insert a duplicate and it gets ignored. You can't trust the lastrowid in that case.

Comment: In this sort of case I usually just use a subquery that returns the parent key.

Comment: Okey, so how do you return the parent key?

Comment: The unique composite value `(name1, name2)` was just inserted, so query the `persons` table for those two values to get the rowid.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Can you please show me? @CPerkins

Comment: Pull `SELECT id FROM Persons WHERE name1 = '…' and name2 = '…'` into **id** (instead of **c.lastrowid**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the appropriate id to use with the scores table with something like:

```
persons = (name1, name2)
c.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO persons (name1, name2) VALUES (?, ?)', persons)
scores = (name1, name2, task, point)
c.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO scores (idPerson, task, score) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM persons WHERE name1=? AND name2=?), ?, ?)', scores)
```